# MYSQL Conditional Insert Into with multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to insert multiple rows while checking each new row against a condition? I know that you can run a simple insert into with multiple rows

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)

AND

INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=VALUES(a), b=VALUES(b), c=VALUES(c)
```

I am attempting to do something like this

```
INSERT INTO x_table(a,b,c) 
    SELECT VALUES(a),VALUES(b),VALUES(c)
        FROM y_table
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM x_table
                             WHERE a != VALUES(a) 
                               AND b != VALUES(b))
```

Test Example (Tested and Working)

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id, timestamp, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5)
SELECT id, timestamp, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5
FROM (SELECT 6783 AS id, FROM_UNIXTIME('1580194194') AS timestamp, 1 AS v1, 0 AS v2, 1 AS v3, 0 AS v4, 45 AS v5
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 6845,FROM_UNIXTIME('1580194194'),1,0,1,0,107
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 6973,FROM_UNIXTIME('1580194194'),1,0,1,0,234
      ) y
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `table` x WHERE x.v1 = y.v1 AND x.v3 = y.v3 AND x.v5 = y.v5 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: 'Is it possible to insert multiple rows ' - no it isn't you can only insert 1 row at a time to a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
INSERT INTO x_table
SELECT a, b, c
FROM (SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, 5 AS c
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4, 5, 6
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 7, 8, 9
      ) y
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM x_table x WHERE x.a = y.a AND x.b = y.b)
```

Note that I think your `EXISTS` clause needs to use `=`, not `!=` otherwise it will be true unless there is only 1 row in `x_table` which has matching `a` and `b` values to the first row to be inserted.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0e6c3260d4bed3e926b836d915852201)

Comment: When attempting this query I get "#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". See updated test example above.. i will fiddle with it and see if i can find out why

Comment: @EricM you're missing `AS id` from the first row of the data i.e. `SELECT 6783 AS id, ...`

Comment: @EricM note it doesn't make any sense to have `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in an `EXISTS` query. `EXISTS` only cares if there is 1 row that matches the condition so whether you order the rows or limit them makes no difference.

Comment: I found that this solution does not work with auto increment index columns as it requires have all fields present in the query for this to work. I removed the index column and my problem went away. Any recommendations?

Comment: Order by is important as I am looking at the most recent value listed in the table, not just any value. Does that change anything?

Comment: @EricM add the column names to the query before insert and leave `id` out of the `SELECT` i.e. `INSERT INTO \`table\` (timestamp, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5) SELECT timestamp, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 FROM (SELECT ...)`

Comment: @EricM yes, makes a *huge* difference. Do you want the latest timestamp for the v1, v3 and v5 values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206769/discussion-between-eric-m-and-nick).

Answer (score 0):

You can do some checks in before insert trigger. Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_x_table_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `x_table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET @found = NULL;

    SELECT
        a INTO @found
    FROM
        y_table
    WHERE
            a = NEW.a
        AND b = NEW.b
    ;

    IF @found IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET @msg = 'Insert failed';
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @msg;
    END IF;
END
```